# Running mongodb on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, systemctl

How can I run Mongodb, as a service, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?
A few days ago I had upgrade my server to Ubuntu 16.04. I have noticed the my MongoDB service does not start when I reboot.
Trying to use

```
sudo initctl start mongod
```

Did not do the trick.
Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Anyone who upgrade or installed Ubuntu 16.04 ( also known as Ubuntu Xenial xerus ) noticed that some of the old services stopped running. 
This issue is known from version 15.04 but I will focus on the above version.

Such was my case with MongoDB. To make a long story, short, Ubuntu shifted from upstart to systemd. One common solution, to these problems, is to switch back to upstart. I do not consider that option as a real solution, certainly not for the long run.

A real solution ( IMHO ) to the problem is to write systemd script that will start MongodDB. Unfortunately MongoDB guys had yet to supply one.

So I had to write one from scratch. To create one of your own follow these steps:

1. switch to root using

   ```
   sudo su
   ```

or use sudo for all the following steps.

2. create a service script (in this example the name of the service is Mongodb)

   ```
   nano /lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service
   ```
3. File content should be

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=MongoDB Database Service
   Wants=network.target
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
   ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
   Restart=always
   User=mongodb
   Group=mongodb
   StandardOutput=syslog
   StandardError=syslog

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

You can also download the file from here:
[mongodb.service](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5g40ynUuGy6MzlRY01lTmZRcTA)

Here is a quick description of the important fields:
**ExecStart** - Is the command to run. Mongo installs itself under /usr/bin and the configuration file is written at /etc
**User** - The uid of the mongod process.
**Group** - The gid of the mongod process. Note that the user and group are created by the installation.

Now to start mongodb:

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

To stop mongodb service use:

```
sudo systemctl stop mongodb
```

To enable mongodb on startup

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service
```

If you need to refresh the services use:

```
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: I keep seeing this message: `Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked.` What does this mean? :/

Comment: Update: I did a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb` and all is well now. Thanks to this guy: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275509&p=13273670#post13273670

Comment: Hi.
When you try to run mongodb for the first time, using mongod, all new generated files has root authorization. This is not good since mongodb runs with its own user, group.

Comment: I had to modify it to use /etc/mongodb.conf instead of /etc/mongod.conf - but otherwise it worked well. thanks.

Answer (score 39):

The latest version of MongoDB does most of things except one thing for now.
After installing the `MongoDB` on `Ubuntu 16.04.x` , run the commands as follows:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mongod.service
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now most likely `mongod` starts on every boot automatically.

---

This solution also works in case of getting this error:

> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

After run the commands above, the commands below start to work:

```
$ sudo service mongod start
$ mongo
```

---

Similarly, the all services installed must be enabled to run.
For instance, after installation of Ops Manager (a.k.a MMS) the documentation says to run the commend below.

> $ sudo systemctl start mongodb-mms.service

Most likely Ubuntu does not start the service. Because it is not enabled yet. To enable it just run the command below:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mongodb-mms.service
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then try to start the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mongodb-mms.service
```

That's all...

Comment: Thank you brother, you saved my day

Comment: other suggested solutions didn't work on my Ubuntu 16.04 and MongoDB 3.4.1. This one did.

Comment: Thanks, just installed successfully MongoDB version 3.4.10, on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service  worked for me on Ubuntu 18 LTS

Comment: this is the best answer for me

Answer (score 26):

### For People That Want A Fresh Install

I have been struggling with this for 1 hour. Then I found [this page](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/mongodb)
Installing is as easy as doing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

Then to check if everything works:

`sudo service mongodb status`

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Here's the `status` command output: `mongodb.service | Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory) | Active: inactive (dead)` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Yes it is working in Ubuntu 16.04(Xenial). Here's the terminal output:-

● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-12-02 20:57:58 IST; 14min ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
 Main PID: 9827 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─9827 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

Dec 02 20:57:58 bhabani-X550CC systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.

Comment: I also get inactive (dead) message. but its working.

Comment: its `mongod` not `mongodb`

Comment: @chovy I do not think so. What command are you talking about?

Comment: `sudo service mongod restart` i believe. `$ sudo service mongodb restart
Failed to restart mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found.` where using `mongod` works fine.

Comment: this command always install version 3.6.3 but I want to install 4.0.9 or any of 4.0.* but not able to do it

Answer (score 23):

The packages for 3.2+ contain upstart scripts.

First, follow the official [instructions to install](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system):

```
# If you installed the ubuntu package, remove it, if not skip to key import
sudo apt-get remove mongodb
sudo apt-get autoremove
# import key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
# add trusty repos
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
# update apt
sudo apt-get update
# install the package
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Then unmask the `mongodb.service` job (and enable and start it). I believe it was masked because the package includes an upstart jobs as well, so you wouldn't want both of them to start. In our case, however, this is clearly what we want.

```
sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
sudo service mongod start
```

References:

[relevant JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7285)

[related question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757384/can-i-use-14-04-mongodb-packages-with-16-04)

Comment: My issue was regarding an older version (3.0.5) of MongoDb. But thanks for your explenation

Comment: `sudo systemctl unmask mongodb` was the missing piece that solve this issue for me on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I get `mongodb: unrecognized service` error always on `sudo service mongodb enable` in Ubuntu 16.04. But instructions provided are helpful, upvote.

Comment: How do you make it start on boot though? I am using this version but when I reboot my server mongod doesn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

is what worked for me on Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Comment: well, its about time they fixed it. At the time of the post, they had repository linking issues...