# Unable to connect mongodb running on ec2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I am trying to connect with mongodb, But it is giving me error.

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22 connecting to: test
>   2019-09-07T05:17:09.460+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused 2019-09-07T05:17:09.461+0000 E QUERY
>   [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017,
>   connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
>   @(connect):1:6

Tried:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

1. Commenting bindip

```
#network interfaces
net:
 port : 2701
#bindip = [0.0.0.0]
```

2. Setting up this to

```
#network interfaces
net:
 port : 2701
bindip : 0.0.0.0
```

3. Setting up this to

```
#network interfaces
net:
 port : 2701
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

4. Setting up this to

```
#network interfaces
net:
 port : 2701
bindip = [0.0.0.0]
```

Saved this file then :

```
sudo service mongod restart mongo
```

Again connection refused giving same error :

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22 connecting to: test
>   2019-09-07T05:17:09.460+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused 2019-09-07T05:17:09.461+0000 E QUERY
>   [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017,
>   connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
>   @(connect):1:6

Any Help?

Comment: Just curious, Port you are setting is 2701 but the error you are getting on port 27017. Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: @Pacifist_AWS its just typo mistake :(   there is also 27017

Comment: Your logs show 'failed to connect to 127.0.0.1', are you trying to connect from within the ec2 instance? or outside ec2 instance?

Comment: @RajatGoel  within the ec2 instance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058244/11847145 this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, Did you enable the AWS security group for that port since you are connecting remotely?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPCSecurityGroups

Comment: Yes enabled the security groups to 27017 for 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

try with below script :

```
mongod --fork --logpath /opt/app/mongo/mongod.log --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --bind_ip_all
```